# SpreadsheetApp.openById gives unauthorised error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I am trying to trigger a function in Google Apps Scripts, and am using openById("Sheet_Id);
But on using it, I am getting this error:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`
> at saveActiveSheet(Code:2:27)
> at onSelectionChange(Code:27:9)

Answer (score 0):

`onSelectionChange` is a reserved name for a simple trigger. This kind of trigger can't execute methods that require permission to run, like [SpreadsheetApp.openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid). Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers.

You have to design think for another way to run your function, like using a custom menu, a custom dialog, a sidebar, an installable trigger, the Apps Script  REST API or running the function from the Google Apps Script editor.

Comment: I tried running the function from the Google Apps Script Editor, but it assumes the active sheet to be Sheet0 by default, even though the sheet that is open in my Google Sheet is Sheet1, and therefore prints the wrong value.

Comment: function saveActiveSheet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL_OF_THE_SHEET").getActiveSheet();

  console.log(ss.getSheetId());
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('ACTIVE_SHEET', ss.getSheetName());
  return ss.getSheetId();
}

Comment: Follow up questions should be posted as a new question.